# Using from, import, as and dot on the same object

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a folder with several `.py` files, each of them has several functions, but I would like to import just one function (or any object) from each file.

Using this tree:

```
.
├── caller.py
└── functions
    ├── A.py
    ├── B.py
    └── C.py
```

In file `caller` I would like to do something like:

```
from functions import (
    A.funcA as func_a,
    B.funcA as func_b,
    C.funcA as func_c
)
```

This gives a syntax error at `A.funcA` on the dot. Is there a way of achiving this without repating all the time?:

```
from functions.A import funcA as func_a
from functions.B import funcB as func_b
from functions.C import funcC as func_c
```

Note: in my case `functions.A` it longer, something like `X.Y.Z.functions.A`, that's why I really want to avoid rewriting.

Comment: I would just write the full import. You only write it once, then you're done with it. Quoting part of the Zen of Python: "Explicit is better than implicit".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're OK with dropping a level of namespacing, you can re-export the submodule functions in the base `functions` package.

Create an `__init__.py` file under `functions` with the contents

```
from .A import funcA
from .B import funcB
from .C import funcC
```

You'll then be able to import your `funcX` functions directly through `functions` as

```
from functions import (
    funcA as func_a,
    funcB as func_b,
    funcC as func_c,
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Even though it is highly advised against, you could use the built in `__import__` function to achieve this.

[builtins __import__](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__)

This way you could define your imports as strings and pass them along.
However, as said, you should really ask yourself if this if worth it to prevent your repetition.

```
import sys, os

path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'import_test')  # Your child python directory
sys.path.append(path)

_temp = __import__('A', fromlist=['A_VAL', 'a_func']) # Imports A_VAL and a_func from 'import_test\A.py'
print(_temp.A_VAL)
_temp.a_func()
```

You could then also use getattr() to access the imported values / functions.

```
a_val = getattr(_temp, 'A_VAL')
```

Comment: This doesn't actually improve the situation. Even using `__import__` like this, you'd still need to import the three functions separately. Plus, messing with `sys.path` like that is going to create "evil twin" modules and generally make a confusing, buggy mess of things.

Comment: Defining the module/function names as variables, allows you to re-use them and iterate - e.g. via a list comprehension, from where one can unpack them again.
I would never do this in my own project and am aware, that this leads to a "confusing, buggy mess of things", which is why it got pointed out that it is highly advised against. However it does not mean, that it is not possible, what the author asked for.